# Appending/Listing LINQ to XML data

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm currently writing a function to save and read data to/from and XML document through
LINQ. Currently I can write the document just fine, but if I go to add data to an existing item, it simply adds a new item. My goal is to create an address book type system (yes I know there's 1000 out there, it's just a learning project for myself) and I've tried ini and basic text but it seems that XML is the best way to go short of using a local DB like sql. Currently I have:

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\TextXML.xml");
    var data = new XElement("Entry",
    new XElement("Name", textBox1.Text),
    new XElement("Address", richTextBox2.Text),
    new XElement("Comments", richTextBox1.Text));
    doc.Element("Contacts").Add(data);
    doc.Save(@"C:\TextXML.xml");
```

I searched **SO** and can't seem to find how to append/replace.
Now this saves everything properly, even when I add to the document, but if I want to update an entry I'm not sure how to without creating a new "**Entry**" nor am have I gotten the knack of removing one. (I'm somewhat new to C# still and self-taught so pardon anything obvious I've overlooked.)

My second issues revolves around loading the information into textboxes.
I'm able to load a list of Entry names into a listbox, but when I go to open the information from that entry I'm not sure how to properly get the nested info.
With the example above I'd need something similar to the following:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\TextXML.xml");
boxName.Text = The name from the SelectedItem of the list box.
boxAddress.Text = The address child of the element named above etc.
```

Each method I've tried I wind up with a null reference exception, which tells me I'm not pointing to the right thing, but I'm not sure how to get to those things properly.
I've also tried creating a *string* and **var** of the SelectedItem from the list box to help with the naming, and using ToString methods, but still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For replacing values, there are several functions you can use in XElement:

```
Value (property with a public setter)
SetValue()
SetElementValue()
SetAttributeValue()
ReplaceWith()
ReplaceNodes()
```

For example, if you wanted to replace the value in Name:

```
data.Element("Name").SetValue("NewValue");
```

or

```
data.Element("Name").Value = "NewValue";
```

For loading, once you have the XElement node you desire, then it's as simple as doing

```
xelement.Value
```

Or if it's an attribute:

```
xelement.Attribute("AttributeName").Value
```

Using your code as an example:

```
boxName.Text = doc.Element("Entry").Element("Name").Value;
```

Edit to address comment:

If I'm reading your comment right, you're wanting to extract the Name/Address/etc. data from *all* the nodes within the Contacts main node?

If so, then you would probably want something like this:

```
boxName.Text = string.Join(",", doc.Elements("Entry").Select(x => x.Element("Name").Value));
```

This will give you a single string that has all the names in all Entries separated by a comma.  Just change "Name" to "Address" to do the same for addresses.

I'd suggest doing a search for Linq to XML for finding more information about how to use this parsing.

Comment: I still can't seem to target the nodes correctly, I either get everything in the notes contacts, or a list of the elements in it.
I'm trying to target all the **Name**s within Contacts to the listbox, then send their elements' information *(Name, Address etc)* into the textboxes I have.